# RGB colors in windows console C++

Tags: c++, winapi, console, rgb

I wanna try to make a class that will be able to print wide character to console with specific RGB color. I know that console has only 16 of them but first take a look.

> Every color in console palette can be changed by setting the right buffer, so I wrote something like that:
>
> ```
> //ConsolePX
> #include <fcntl.h>
> #include <io.h>
> #include <Windows.h>
> #include <iostream>
> class ConsolePX
>   {
>   public:
>       wchar_t source;
>       COLORREF foreground, background;
>        /* Set at the start ctor */
>       ConsolePX(wchar_t _what, COLORREF foregroundColor, COLORREF backgroundColor)
>       {
>           source = _what;
>           foreground = foregroundColor;
>           background = backgroundColor;
>       }
>       /* Draws wchar_t with colors to console */
>       void Draw() {
>           HANDLE outH = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
>           CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX curr, newBuff;
>           curr.cbSize = sizeof(CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX);
>           GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(outH, &curr);
>           curr.srWindow.Bottom++;
>           newBuff = curr;
>           newBuff.ColorTable[0] = background;
>           newBuff.ColorTable[1] = foreground;
>           SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(outH, &newBuff);
>           SetConsoleTextAttribute(outH, 1);
>           _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);   //Sets console mode to 16-bit unicode
>           std::wcout << source << std::endl;
>           _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_TEXT);
>
>           //Restores to defaults
>           SetConsoleTextAttribute(outH, 7);   
>           SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(outH, &curr);
>       }
>   };
> ```
>
> ```
> //Driver code
> #include "ConsolePX.h"
> int main()
> {
>    ConsolePX(L'█', RGB(29, 219, 79), RGB(0, 0, 0)).Draw();
>    return 0;
> }
> ```

And that worked but the problem is in the last line in `ConsolePX`(exactly `SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(outH, &curr)`). After printing `wchar_t` I restored palette to defaults. Why is that a problem? I noticed that every char in a console isn't pinned to color but to the color palette index, so after restoring to defaults palette, I restored `wchar_t` color too. After deleting that line, I'll interfere with the rest of the code. Is there any way to block x, y character in the console to avoid color change?
Of important things, I'm using Visual Studio and, as you can guess, I'm using windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

You said it yourself: there are 16 colours available to you.

When you thought you'd bypassed that restriction, actually all you were doing was changing what those colours "mean", i.e. what RGB values they map to for that console.

The current palette applies to the whole content of the console. If it didn't, we wouldn't be limited to 16 colours.

So, while your attempt is inventive, I'm afraid it fundamentally cannot work.

If you want control over real colours like this, make a GUI application.

Comment: The Windows console supports [Console Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) (starting with Windows 10). When using [extended colors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#extended-colors) you aren't restricted to a 16 color palette.

Comment: @IInspectable From that page: _"Some virtual terminal emulators support a palette of colors greater than the 16 colors provided by the Windows Console. For these extended colors, the Windows Console will choose the nearest appropriate color from the existing 16 color table for display."_ So, though the datastream will have RGB encoded in it, unless you're using some other console that actually supports them, this is probably not exactly what you intended. OP's question title says Windows Console. A graphical application is the way to go for graphics.

Comment: That information is outdated: [24-bit Color in the Windows Console!](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/24-bit-color-in-the-windows-console/)

Comment: @IInspectable Well, now we're talking!